# Django 'this field is required' form error on non-editable field

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-forms

I'm trying to build a form that lets me categorise/edit my bank transactions.
Ideally all uncategorised transactions will be displayed on one page (in a formset) and I'll be able to edit some/all of them. When I hit 'submit' on the formset, I want to save any changes and navigate to a confirmation page.

Here's my model for a Transaction:

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField('date')
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
    uuid = models.CharField(
         max_length=200,
         primary_key = True,
         unique = True, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description
```

Date, description, and amount are important to show on the form because they help me figure out how to categorise the transaction. I don't want to accidentally edit the date or amount, so I've made them readonly on the form. Transactions also have `uuid` and `account` fields, but those are irrelevant to categorisation and I don't want to edit them, so they shouldn't be shown at all.

My form and formset look like this:

```
class TransactionForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Transaction
    exclude = ('uuid', 'account')
  
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(TransactionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    cat = self.fields['category']
    cat.required = False
    cat.blank = True
    self.fields['description']
    self.fields['amount'].readonly = True
    self.fields['post_date'].readonly = True

TransactionFormset = modelformset_factory(Transaction, form=TransactionForm)
```

If I try to edit some transactions and submit this formset, I get an error on each form that says "uuid - This field is required.". I'm having a hard time understanding why `uuid` matters to the form, if I've (a) explicitly excluded it in the form construction and (b) made the field editable=False at the model level

The view I'm using to render the formset is:

```
class TransactionFormView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.list.ListView):
    login_url = 'accounts/login'
    redirect_field_name = 'redirect_to'
    template_name = 'transactions_form.html'

    model = Transaction

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        
        formset = TransactionFormset()
        
        context['formset'] = formset
        context['saved'] = False
        return context
  
    def post(self, request):
        formset = TransactionFormset(request.POST)
        foundValid = False
        for i, form in enumerate(formset): 
            if (form.is_valid() and form.initial):
                form_info = form.save(commit=False)
                xact = Transaction.objects.filter(uuid=form.initial['uuid']).first()
                if xact:
                    xact.category = form_info.category
                    xact.description = form_info.description
                    xact.save()
                    foundValid = True
                
            else:
                logger.info(form.errors)

        if foundValid:

            messages.success(request, "Transactions processed! Thanks for sorting :)")
        return render(request, "transactions_form.html", {"formset" : formset , "saved": foundValid })
```

and finally, the template the view operates on is:

```
{% block content %}
{% if saved %}
<h1>Thanks!</h1>
Your transactions have been categorised.
<a href="{% url 'fill' %}">[Want to do more?]</a>

{% else %}
<table>
<tr>
  <th>Date</th>
  <th>Description</th>
  <th>Amount</th>
  <th>Category</th>
</tr>

<form method="post">
{{ formset.management_form }}
{% csrf_token %}
{% for form in formset %}
    <tr>
     {{ form.errors }}
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>{{ form.post_date }}</td>
      <td>{{ form.description }}</td>
      <td>{{ form.amount }}</td>
      <td>{{ form.category }}</td> 
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: `uuid` field is essential in this case as it is a primary key for your model and creation of the new objects as well as editing existing ones inside of the formset relies on it. On the model level, you don't define how this field is generated and there is no logic for in on the form level either. You could use `default=uuid.uuid4` while defining your model and add uuid as a disabled field in the form https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/fields/#disabled

Comment: I'm using this form to edit Transaction objects that already exist, so they all have uuids set. Is there a way to pass that info with the form response without having it visible in the form?

Comment: Hi @Makxine, 
there is a way to render the field as hidden `{{ form.uuid.as_hidden }}` in this case the field will be hidden from the UI but you will still be able to process in the form.